# Duplicating a linked list C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

Not sure as to why my function is not working, I think the logic should be correct:

```
template<typename T>
struct node{
    T _item;
    node<T>* _next;
    node<T>* _prev;
    node(const T& item = T(), node<T>* next = NULL, node<T>* prev = NULL):
    _item(item), 
    _next(next),
    _prev(prev){}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& outs, const node<T>& print_me){
        outs<<"["<<print_me._item<<"]->";
        return outs;
    }
};
```

Function:

```
template <typename T>
node<T>* _copy_list(node<T>* head) {
    node<T>* copy = new node<T>;
    while (head != NULL) {
        copy ->_item = head ->_item;  // copy's value = head's value
        // next value of copy = next value after head
        copy ->_next = _copy_list(head ->_next);
        return copy;
    } 
}
```

[420]->[90]->[80]->[70]->[652]->[60]->[50]->[40]->[30]->[20]->[69]->[0]->|||
Copy:
[420]->[90]->[80]->[70]->[652]->[60]->[50]->[40]->[30]->[20]->[69]->[0]->[0]->|||

Comment: Looks like you forgot the `return`.

Comment: You never set the `_prev` values, and your recursion will never bottom out because you don't have any special logic for what should happen when `head` is `NULL`.

Comment: I removed all of the C++ Standard tags because there's no functionality specific to any of them at issue here. Typically you should use only one Standard tag because it's exceedingly unlikely that you're building a program to more than one C++ Standard revision at a time.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to write a recursive method to copy a linked list ? Can you simply use the iterative method with 1 ```while``` loop to copy a linked list, which is much simpler and easier to implement ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` should be after the `while` loop.  If `head` is NULL, the loop breaks, and you leak the new `node`, as well as leave the return value of `_copy_list()` *indeterminate*, which is **undefined behavior**.

But, since you are using a recursive loop, you don't actually need the `while` loop at all.

Also, you are not setting the `_prev` member of any of the new `node`s.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
template <typename T>
node<T>* _copy_node(node<T>* n, node<T>* prev) {
    if (!n) return NULL;
    node<T>* copy = new node<T>(n->_item, NULL, prev);
    copy->_next = _copy_node(n->_next, copy);
    return copy;
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* _copy_list(node<T>* head) {
    return _copy_node(head, NULL);
}
```

Which would be better implemented as an iterative loop instead of a recursive loop, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
node<T>* _copy_list(node<T>* head) {
    node<T> *copy = NULL, *prev = NULL;
    node<T> **n = &copy;
    while (head) {
        *n = new node<T>(head->_item, NULL, prev);
        prev = *n;
        n = &(prev->_next);
        head = head->_next;
    } 
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

```
template <typename T>
node<T>* _copy_list(node<T>* head) {
     if (head == NULL) {
     return head;
     }
     node<T>* copy = new node<T>(head ->_item);
     copy ->_next = _copy_list(head ->_next);
     return copy;

}
```

Comment: You are still not setting the `_prev` member of the new `node`s.